# How to refer to a User Control host's StaticResource inside the control?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following `StaticResource` in my `Window.Resources`

```
<my:someobj x:Key="someResource" />
```

I have a user control inside window. I need to refer to the above resource inside of my user control, how can I do this ? I cannot move resource to a separate dictionary file.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource someResource}, Path=SomeText}" />
```

The above gives me compile error that `someResource` is not found. How can I refer to `someResource` ?

Answer (score 3):

You will get your answer once resource look up behavior is clear to you. From [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613(v=vs.110).aspx), it works like this:

> 1. The lookup process checks for the requested key within the resource
>      dictionary defined by the element that sets the property.
> 2. The lookup process then traverses the logical tree upward, to the parent element
>      and its resource dictionary. This continues until the root element is
>      reached.
> 3. Next, application resources are checked. Application
>      resources are those resources within the resource dictionary that is
>      defined by the Application object for your WPF application.

In your case ***window is not logical parent of UserControl.*** Hence, can't find the resource there. So, you can ***move the resource under application resources*** where it will be available for your UserControl.

```
<Application.Resources>
   <my:someobj x:Key="someResource" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Converter={StaticResource konv} }" />
```

and in Converter

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is Window ? ((Window)value).Resources["someResource"] : "Error";
    }
```

Comment: nice tweak sir!

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve this prob as:

> Solution1:Add the resource someobj  to ResourceDictionary and Merge it in App.xaml like
>   REsourceDictionary.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:my="clr-namespace:StackOverFlowValidations"
                >
<my:ABC x:Key="myObj"/>
```

> App.xaml

```
    <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

> Solution2: Add this resource to UserControl instead of Window.
>
> Solution3: Add this Resource to Window as DynamicResoure like

```
        public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Resources.Add("myObj", new ABC());
    }

 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={DynamicResource someResource}, Path=SomeText}" />
```